# where does "request" come from in CQ5?

Tags: aem

I am new to CQ5.

While I was trying to follow the official guide of how to create a website at 
[https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/howto/website.html], the following code confused me.

```
Iterator<Page> children = rootPage.listChildren(new PageFilter(request));
```

I did not find any reference of "request". Can someone tell me where it comes from?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `request` is an instance of the [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) that is available implicitly in any JSP file. ([Full list here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm)).

Hence you can use them directly without explicitly declaring them.

In AEM (CQ5), apart from the JSP implicit objects, you can get quick access to few `AEM`, `Sling` and `JCR` specific objects by including the `global.jsp` file in your JSP as shown below.

`<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>`

This entire list of objects and tag libraries that would be available through your global.jsp can be [found here](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/scripts.html).

Comment: Thanks Rakhi. great tip.

Comment: In CQ/AEM you also have an extended version of the request and response objects: slingRequest of type SlingHttpServletRequest and slingResponse of type SlingHttpServletResponse. In many API's from CQ you'll rather need these instead of the plain HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse.

Comment: @Thomas agreed. That is why I mentioned the use of global.jsp, so that he gets to know all the available objects that can be leveraged during development. :)